# iOS: Add an image to the Navigation bar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm currently working on an iOS app that is pretty much supposed look and work like an already existing android app.

As a part of that, I'd like to make the top navigation look the same, but since iOs devices do not provide a hardware or software integrated back button, I'd also like to keep the back button navigation that's common to iOs apps.

I've tried numerous attempts to achieve it, but I'll stick with the latest I'm working on since it looks the most promising. I've started to work on a custom `UINavigationBar` class that overrides the `initWithCoder:` and `layoutSubviews:` methods. The result is as follows:

[image]

As you can see, the back button now overlaps the application icon. What I'm looking for is a way to make the button and the text to scale into the space right of the application icon. I've tried to handle this in `layoutSubviews:` but the superclass logic appears to be rather complex, I was not able to reproduce it's functionality (in particular it seems to be working with some private variables I don't have access to).

I also tried manipulating `self.frame` before calling `[super layoutSubviews]` but apart from endless loops I was not able to achieve anything in that direction.

I'd be happy if anyone could point me into the right direction.

Comment: Write `Tracker` instead `Bladeguard Tracker` and put the icon elsewhere. You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, I think you could do this by adding a custom titleView to the UINavigationItem, and have an image view (on the left side for the icon) and a label (for the title) as subviews. This would replace the default title.

Comment: wouldn't that bring the application icon between the back button and the title? my intention is to have the application icon on the very left, followed by the button and the title

Comment: @JakobKetterl, yeah, you're right, I misinterpreted your question.

Comment: @JakobKetterl, I'm assuming that the Android app doesn't have the back button in the navigation bar, is that correct? Is so, then you've already changed the look pretty significantly, so why not put the icon on the right -- I think it would look better there anyway.

Comment: you're right, the android app just has an icon and the title string. putting the icon on the right wouldn't really make a big difference. the screenshot is just an example, if the icon was on the right i'd have the same problem when the title string gets longer...